# How to pass the value in consoletvs charts using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I want to pass the average time and the user e-mail in consoletvs/charts i worte the SQL for that

```
$currentTime = Carbon::today();

$time_difference = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT `acu_name` ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, acu_at, acu_et)) as averageTime
FROM `active_user`
WHERE acu_at <= '$currentTime' GROUP BY `acu_name`"));
```

in this SQL result is coming when i get this through foreach method but if pass this through charts it's showing an error

```
 $chart = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title('Total Clients Average Using Time')
            ->elementLabel("Total")
            ->labels($time_difference->acu_name)
            ->values($time_difference->averageTime)
            ->responsive(false);
```

Error Message is :

[image]

I can't understand what is the issues please help me to find out the issue
and i attached my database structure and dummy data screen shots.
My php version is 7.3.2
Laravel version is 5.5

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you do `DB::select()` it gives you array having stdClass objects representing the found rows. So even if you expect one resultant row coming out of your `DB::select()` query, the result will be still inside an array.

So when you are doing following :

```
$currentTime = Carbon::today();

$time_difference = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT `acu_name` ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, acu_at, acu_et)) as averageTime
FROM `active_user`
WHERE acu_at <= '$currentTime' GROUP BY `acu_name`"));
```

It is returning an array and inside that there are records matching.

You either need to do `foreach()` to loop through `$time_difference` array or do `$time_difference[0]-> acu_name`

Also, your `DB::raw` contains a user defined variable which is a danger for SQL injections.

**Update :**

Please check [documentation](https://charts.erik.cat/adding_datasets.html#database-eloquent-example) where there are nice examples for the eloquent way of doing this.

Comment: i tried your method 

count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\mvc-panel\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: I have added documentation link of the package you re using which would  help you. The error you are getting is from using the chsrt package, as it expects certain structure of data

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks indeed strange that this specific error is being thrown. However we can see in you provided code that you store the following in your `$time_difference` variable:

```
DB::select(...);
```

Usually this returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` which is an object if I am not mistaking.

If you take a look into the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L220) you can see that this function does return `$this` which is an instance of the above mentioned.

What I can say that is missing is the execution of the query. Usually a `select()` is followed by a `get()` or a `first()` as shown in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects).

Another action you should undertake is to validate of anything has been returned after the execution of your query. You final code with some tweaks could look like:

```
$time_difference = DB::table('active_user')
    ->select([
        'acu_name',
        DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, acu_at, acu_et)) as averageTime'),
    ])
    ->where('acu_at', '<=', $currentTime)
    ->groupBy('acu_name')
    ->first(); // Be aware this will only return the first row. Not sure if this is what you inted to do.


if (is_null($time_difference)) {
    // Do something when it has not been found.
}


 $chart = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
    ->title('Total Clients Average Using Time')
    ->elementLabel("Total")
    ->labels($time_difference->acu_name)
    ->values($time_difference->averageTime)
    ->responsive(false);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')' this error is showing

Comment: @Jerad It's just a missing ).  Look over the code, put in the missing ) and see if it works

Comment: @Jerad Thanks for the notice. I have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: after that this error is coming
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\mvc-panel\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen please give a solution